# Any ideas on how to solve this trig equation: $\tan(\pi/4+x)= 3\tan(\pi/4-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\newcommand\tg{\operatorname{tg}}\tg(\pi/4+x)= 3\tg(\pi/4-x)$

If I take the arctg of both sides then this is equal to:

$\pi/4+x = 3(\pi/4-x) $

$x=\pi/8$

Is this correct?

Comment: No. For one, $\arctan 3 u \neq 3 \arctan u$.

Comment: so what is arctan(3tan(pi/4-x)) equal to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)={\frac {-1+\cot \left( x \right) }{1+\cot \left( x \right) }}$$
and 
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)={\frac {1+\tan \left( x \right) }{1-\tan \left( x \right) }}$$

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using the cotangent in the first formula instead of the simpler $\tan(\pi/4-x)=\dfrac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}$.

Comment: so if  $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)= {\tan {\pi\over 4}- \tan x\over 1+ \tan {\pi\over 4}\tan x}  $$
$${\tan {\pi\over 4}- \tan x\over 1+ \tan {\pi\over 4}\tan x}= {1-\tan x\over 1+\tan x}$$  how is $${1-\tan x\over 1+\tan x}={\frac {-1+\cot \left( x \right) }{1+\cot \left( x \right) }}$$

Comment: @user276719 Why the question in your comment if you accept this answer?